# Android, Saving data that won't be deleted even after I uninstall the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to save data from my application and keep them on device even after I uninstall the application, so when I reinstall the app I will still have the data stored previously.

I know about allowBackup which I can set to true/false in Manifest, but I wonder is there any way to store data on device, not online?

Comment: Why would the user want this?

Comment: Not sure, I got the task asking for this... I read about using external storage  which user and other apps can than see... but is there a way to save data locally and keep it private to app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save data to external storage, and encrypt it using a key only your app knows. Keep in mind this would not be entirely safe, as a malicious app could get the key from your apk beforehand and use it to decrypt the data.